# GNU parallel: command line too long (47 >= 0)

Tags: gnu-parallel

I was running several hundred similar jobs as a SLURM job array.

Each job included the following command to compress two files, ${SAMPLE_ID}_kneaddata_paired_1.fastq and ${SAMPLE_ID}_kneaddata_paired_2.fastq:

```
parallel --jobs 2 gzip ::: ${SAMPLE_ID}_kneaddata_paired_*.fastq
```

In 45 cases, the command did not compress the files and an error message like this appeared:

```
parallel: Error: Command line too long (47 >= 0) at input 0: XYZ.1230000456789_kneaddata_paired_1.fastq
```

On the other hand, the following command returns "131071":

```
parallel --max-line-length-allowed
```

Could you please advise what may cause this problem and how to fix it?
Thank you!

Comment: Provide some [mre] in your question. The error message seems clear enough to me. **Did you read the documentation of [GNU gzip](https://www.gnu.org/software/gzip/) and of [GNU parallel](https://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/) and [glob(7)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/glob.7.html) and [execve(2)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/execve.2.html) ?**

Comment: Also, all the programs you mention in your question are [free software](https://www.gnu.org/philosophy/free-sw.en.html) so you are allowed to download and improve their source code

Comment: I'm encountering this with `LIST=$(ls ~)` followed by `parallel --tmuxpane --fg "echo {}" ::: $LIST`... we wanted to use tmux integration to reproduce an ssh command throwing up an interactive password prompt randomly about 0.5% of the time.. so being able to see the output in tmux panes was meaningfully important to our use case. For me, on MacOS 11.6.5, the above commands yield `parallel: Error: Command line too long (48 >= -1622) at input 0: Applications`

Comment: Same with `echo words > list.txt` followed by `parallel --tmuxpane --fg -a list.txt "echo {}"`. For me, this yields `parallel: Error: Command line too long (18 >= -1622) at input 0: words`.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
parallel --jobs 2 gzip :::: <(ls ${SAMPLE_ID}_kneaddata_paired_*.fastq)
```